# Do I need to create a controller for a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode4, xcode4.2

Just starting out with an iPhone application using xcode 4.2.

I understand that it is good practice to use a subclass of UIViewController for each view in my application, and I am able to write some basic code in these to test buttons etc on the associated view.

Now I want to perform some action on a text field in one of these views, let's say I will use the Value Changed event to log the textfield's contents on each keystroke.

Should I be creating some kind of UITextField controller subclass?  Or do I deal with this kind of thing in the existing ViewController subclass that houses the textfield?

If the latter, how do I refer to the textfield in the view controller subclass, and make the connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the existing ViewController subclass that houses the textfield. A good rule of thumb is one ViewController per screen of views (not including UINavigationController, Modal screens, uisplitviewcontroller, and popovers).

To refer to it, you would make a property in the .h of your custom UIViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField * myTextField;
```

Note the IBOutlet keyword. This will allow you to connect it in InterfaceBuilder (or your storyboard). To learn how to connect that I would recommend you watch a video about IBOutlets since its more of a visual thing.

Comment: Many thanks. I was able to also access the textfield by declaring it as an ivar - is there any particular benefit to making a property?  Is the property in case another class needs access?

Comment: I like to make them properties because it's more explicitly defined as to whether they are strong, weak or assign (though you can do that with ivars as well, and both default to strong). I kind of see an Outlet as something that is access from the outside of the class, since it's set in IB/Storyboard, but that doesn't necessarily mean you have to do it that way since it uses introspection to set them. I believe the latest samples from Apple have IBOutlets set as properties though so that's the convention I follow.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want your `UIViewController` to implement [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html). Connections can be made via the Interface Builder and outlets or just setting the delegate on the text field and using the reference you get from the delegate callbacks.